# Panel data: np.where with a groupby?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

In the following data frame i want to create a new binary variable 0 or 1 according to a certain conditions. The condition is id's which in t-1 size is lower or equal than 2, in t size must be bigger than 2 and in t+1 size should be bigger than 2. And also that the year t+1 should be consecutive to t

My dataframe look like this

```
id    year    size   
1     2008       2       
1     2009       3       
1     2010       3       
2     2011       1       
2     2012       1       
2     2013       1       
3     2009       3       
3     2010       2       
3     2011       3       
3     2012       3
```

I tried to use the np.where function

```
df['new_variable'] = np.where((df.year.shift(-1) == df.year+ 1) & (df.year<2016) & (df.size.shift(1) < 3) & (df.size>2) & (df.size.shift(-1) > 2),1,0)
```

but first i need to perform this np.where by id because if i performed my np.where code result would be like this, so that's why i need first a ´groupby´ but doesn't allow to do it.

```
id    year    size   new variable
1     2008       2       0
1     2009       3       1
1     2010       3       0
2     2011       1       0
2     2012       1       0
2     2013       1       0
3     2009       3       1    #this 1 it's incorrect, because a new id begin
3     2010       2       1
3     2011       3       0
3     2012       3       0
```

Real output should look like this

```
id    year    size   new variable
1     2008       2       0
1     2009       3       1
1     2010       3       0
2     2011       1       0
2     2012       1       0
2     2013       1       0
3     2009       3       0    
3     2010       2       1
3     2011       3       0
3     2012       3       0
```

Comment: You have some syntax issues with your statement.  df.size is not the same as df['size'], because size is an attribute of the dataframe object.  Using the short cut df.col is not a good idea when you have column names that are attributes of the dataframe object.  Therefore, I recommend you use df['size'].   Type df.size and you will get a return of 30.  Now type df['size'], you get the series for column size.